# PDO & MSSQL - How to change the timezone per connection

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2012, timezone

I'm looking to set the timezone (per session) on a PDO-MSSQL connection so that getdate() can be used to store and return local times of a user rather than the servers default (Europe/London)

Google returns hundreds of results for MYSQL; but nothing for MSSQL. So it looks like this is the answer for MYSQL:

$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'

Is there an equivalent for MSSQL?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SQL Server does not have the concept of a *session time zone*, so the answer to your question is simply - No.

However, there are solutions for working with time zones in SQL Server.  With SQL Server 2016, support was added for [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql) so one can convert data elements between time zones (similar to MySQL's `CONVERT_TZ` function).  This uses Microsoft Windows time zone identifiers though, not standard IANA / TZDB identifiers.  If you want support for those (such as `Europe/London` you mentioned), then you'll need to use something like my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) open-source project.

Either of those approaches is only required if you really need to do time zone conversions at the database layer.  In the vast majority of cases, you don't actually need to do that.  Instead, handle time zone conversions at the application layer.  PHP has really good support for time zones, so you shouldn't need to do it in the database.

If you had a specific scenario in mind, then ask a new question about that (after searching to see if it's already been asked).

Comment: Thanks - I had a feeling this was coming; I can deal with it at the application layer as you say; it just would have been much easier to add a single line at the connection!